# Any one way Encryption Method better than MD5 ? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I`m searching for an Encryption Method better than MD5. It must be one way encryption because I do not want to use keys in encryption.

Comment: have fun decrypting it. Which will be even harder in SHA-1 or SHA-256. Does that make SHA-256 better or worse than MD5?

Comment: Khaled, you should probably read http://forum.codecall.net/blogs/wingedpanther/244-encryption-vs-hashing.html. Someone voted you down for not knowing the difference between encryption and hashing.

Comment: If you are going to down vote you should at least explain why so the OP can amend their question. Site shouldn't be about ego boosting or slating it should be about sharing knowledge in a nice, clean and readable fashion.

Comment: A google search for "c# encryption methods" is a much better starting point than an open ended question with no scenarios presented, some research from the OP can be followed up with specific programming questions if you have any difficulties implementing anything you find. The answers already given have probably not answered his question because they're about hashing and not encryption, as the question was not clear.

Comment: Dear all,sorry for this mistake, i am using MD5 to Encrypt the Login Password .. so i call it encryption..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a Hashing algorithm not an encryption.
you can use more stable [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)

```
using(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
{ 
   System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();   
   byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(str);   
   hash.ComputeHash(combined);   
}
```

**EDIT**: answer to comments

[System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx)

> The hash is used as a unique value of fixed size representing a large
>   amount of data. Hashes of two sets of data should match if the
>   corresponding data also matches. Small changes to the data result in
>   large, unpredictable changes in the hash.
>
> The hash size for the SHA1 algorithm is 160 bits.

Comment: @sllev, as I recently discovered, `SHA1` in an `IDisposable`, so you might want to wrap its usage in a `using` statement

Comment: @Zruty: Let this .NET tip up to Khaled ;) I just illustrated an example related to SHA1. But anyway thanks I'll update answer

Comment: How is SHA-1 "more stable" than MD5?

Comment: @LukeH: basically there is less possibility that you'll get the same hashes for different data, obviously because SHA1 uses 160 vs 128 of MD5

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is not an encryption method, because you can not decrypt the message given its MD5 hash. It's a hashing algorithm: given an arbitrary message it computes its 'digest' (hence the algorithm name).

MD5 can be used as a means of signing messages, by computing the MD5-hash of the (message + shared secret) combination.

There are other hashing algorithms, for example `SHA1` and `SHA256`, you can use them in your code instead of MD5.